# Can I share my Mylyn local repository?

Tags: eclipse, bug-tracking, bugzilla, mylyn, connector

I'm an independent developer but sometimes switch between computers.  I would love it if I could maintain a single Mylyn task repository.  However, from what I've seen, the offered connectors each use proprietary task formats and strangely don't seem to offer the ability to organize tasks hierarchically (nested subtasks nicely displayed indented in the editor).

I know I can change where the task data is stored, but I'm sure things wouldn't work well if I tried to access the task database concurrently from two computers over the network.  And besides, this wouldn't work if the remote computer were offline.

Is there any way to reliably share and keep in sync local tasks in an environment like this?

Answer (score 0):

Creators of Mylyn are most interested to support connectors to commercial issue tracking applications and ALM tools.

However you can use import/export functions available from popup menu in the Task List view. Or just use drag and drop from Task List view to a local folder, drop box in a web browser or your email client.

Alternatively you could install standalone issue tracker such as Trac or JIRA (only $10 for 10 users).

Comment: I take it that Trac and JIRA don't support hierarchical subtasks as I said I was looking for in the question, right?  And the import/export would have to be done every time I switch computers.  Even then, I presume I'd first have to delete all the tasks on the importing computer, right?

Comment: JIRA does support hierarchical subtasks (one level though). Import/Export is manual, so yes, you'll need to do that every time. Not sure if it will merge existing tasks, but that's easy enough to verify.

Comment: Almost forgot that you can use drag and drop from task list, even that I somewhat had a hand in that while back... :)